# Sending Camfootage from Raspi (Python) to Windows (Java) via Socket -> Inpustream gets stucked

Tags: python, java, image, sockets, picamera

I am trying to send pictures of my Raspi to my PC. The program on the Raspi runs with Python. Since my main programming language is Java, I want to process the images in a JAVA application. As a template I took the demo program of the Raspicam documentation.

https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes1.html#capturing-to-a-network-stream

Here is my code
Python:

```
import socket
import struct
import time
import picamera

# Connect a client socket to my_server:8000 (change my_server to the
# hostname of your server)
client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(('192.168.0.106', 8000))

# Make a file-like object out of the connection
connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')
try:
    camera = picamera.PiCamera()
    camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    # Start a preview and let the camera warm up for 2 seconds
    camera.start_preview()
    time.sleep(2)

    # Note the start time and construct a stream to hold image data
    # temporarily (we could write it directly to connection but in this
    # case we want to find out the size of each capture first to keep
    # our protocol simple)
    start = time.time()
    stream = io.BytesIO()
    while(True):
        inputsignal= client_socket.recv(1)
        if(inputsignal==b'\x01'):
            
           
            camera.capture(stream, 'jpeg')
            size =stream.tell()
            stream.seek(0)
            print(size)
            connection.write(struct.pack('<L', size))
            connection.flush()
           

            connection.write(stream.read())
            connection.flush()
                   
            
            stream.seek(0)
            stream.truncate(0)
            
            
            
            print("Bild wurde gesendet")
            
            continue
        if(inputsignal==b'\xFF'):
            connection.write(struct.pack('<L', 0))
            break
   
finally:
    connection.close()
    client_socket.close()
```

Java Server

```
public static void getInetStream() {
            try {           
                BufferedImage bim;
                ServerSocket ssocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
                System.out.println("Warte auf Verbindung...");
                Socket s1 = ssocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Verbindung hergestellt"+ s1.getInetAddress());
                System.out.println("Warte auf Daten...");
                OutputStream os = s1.getOutputStream();
                InputStream stream = s1.getInputStream() ;
                while(s1.isConnected()) {
                    //Force new Frame
                    os.write(1);
                    System.out.println("Neuer Frame wird geladen");
                    byte[] length = new byte[8];
                    stream.read(length);
                    int size= (length[3]<<24)&0xff000000|
                               (length[2]<<16)&0x00ff0000|
                               (length[1]<< 8)&0x0000ff00|
                               (length[0]<< 0)&0x000000ff;
                    
                    
                    System.out.println("Größe:"+size+" Bytes");
                    
                    
                    bim = ImageIO.read(stream); 
                    
                    System.out.println("Bild empfangen: "+bim.getHeight()+"/"+bim.getWidth());
                    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bim));
                    label.repaint();
                }               
     
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The main problem now is that although all the data is transferred, the image gets stuck in the Inputstream. If I write another byte, the new byte as well as the complete image is transferred. Maybe ImageIO.read() is the Problem.

Here is my Output from the Console:
Java

```
Warte auf Verbindung...
Verbindung hergestellt/192.168.0.143
Warte auf Daten...
Neuer Frame wird geladen
Größe:239021 Bytes
```

Python

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/Camsocket.py
239021
Bild wurde gesendet
```

As you can see Python must have sent the image successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works for me.
I don't let ImageIO read the data directly, but write it first into a Array with defined size via BufferedInputStream. I can't say yet if there is a more efficient way. I achieve approx. 4fps, whereby a large part goes on the data transfer. The processing by ImageIO + output to the frame is about 10-20ms.
The Code below works with the Demo from the PICamera dokumentation:
https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes1.html#capturing-to-a-network-stream
Just copy the Pythoncode and put it on your Raspi. It should work just fine.
Sometimes the size doesn`t get read correctly. This will cause an Error.

Java Server:

```
public static void getInetStream() {
            try {       
                long last_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long current_time =0;
                BufferedImage bim;
                ServerSocket ssocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
                System.out.println("Warte auf Verbindung...");
                Socket s1 = ssocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Verbindung hergestellt"+ s1.getInetAddress());
                System.out.println("Warte auf Daten...");
                OutputStream os = s1.getOutputStream();
                InputStream stream = s1.getInputStream() ;
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
                byte[] length = new byte[4];
                byte[] data;
                while(s1.isConnected()) {
                    //Force new Frame
                    //os.write(1);
                    System.out.println("Neuer Frame wird geladen");
                    current_time=System.currentTimeMillis();
                    System.out.println("Delay: "+(current_time-last_time)+" ms");
                    last_time=System.currentTimeMillis();
                    stream.read(length);
                    int size= (length[3]<<24)&0xff000000|
                               (length[2]<<16)&0x00ff0000|
                               (length[1]<< 8)&0x0000ff00|
                               (length[0]<< 0)&0x000000ff;
                    
                    if(size<=0) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    data=new byte[size];
                    
                    System.out.println("Größe:"+size+" Bytes");
                    int data_ready;
                    int offset =0;
                    int readed =0;
                    while(true) {
                        data_ready = bis.available();
                        //System.out.println(data_ready);
                        
                        if(data_ready>0) {
                            System.out.println("Offset: "+offset+" Bytes");
                            readed = bis.read(data,offset,size-offset);
                            
                            
                            offset=offset+readed;
                            System.out.println("Datenpaket empfangen:"+readed+" Bytes");
                            if(offset==size) {
                                break;
                            }
                                                        
                        }
                        
                    }
                    current_time=System.currentTimeMillis();
                    System.out.println("Dauer Datenempfang: "+(current_time-last_time)+" ms");
                    last_time=System.currentTimeMillis();
                    
                    bim=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
                    System.out.println("Daten empfangen");
                    System.out.println("Bild empfangen: "+bim.getHeight()+"/"+bim.getWidth());
                    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bim));
                    label.repaint();
                    
                }               
     
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
```